# Android 13+ problems writing and reading files

Tags: java, android

Now on Android 13+ , it shows the grant permission , i allow it and then when i try to read or write text files from/to:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
```

It doesn't work. What I find even more confusing is that i have some code that writes a png image of the application , is working , but not the writing to text file portion.

Also another thing that I find difficult to understand is that in android studio if i have a android 13 or 14 emulator , it works , but not on the real phone.

Here are the 2 types: The image that is saving correctly:

```
private void writeScreenShotToFile(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray)
{
        askPermissionComponent.askForWritePermission();
        askPermissionComponent.verifyIfFolderExist();

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dataComponent.getSavedImage(getLoadedMonth()));

            combineImages(bitmapArray).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            errorBuilderComponent.errorConstructor("error");
        }
}
```

And the code that is not working:

```
public void loadFromFile()
{
    askPermissionComponent.askForWritePermission();
    askPermissionComponent.verifyIfFolderExist();

    if (dataComponent.getSavedFile(dataComponent.getCurrentMonth()).exists())
    {

writeDataFromFileToTable(dataComponent.getSavedFile(dataComponent.getCurrentMonth()));
    }

}
```

This gets its data from:

```
public File getSavedFile(String month)
{
    return new File(getSDCardLocation(month) + ".txt");
}

public File getSavedImage(String month)
{
    return new File(getSDCardLocation(month) + ".png");
}

private String getSDCardLocation(String month)
{
    return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)  + "/TEST/" + month;
}
```

Now below I will write the class that I use for asking for permission:

```
public class AskForWritePermission
{
    private final MainActivity mainActivityComponent;
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 112;

    public AskForWritePermission(MainActivity mainActivityComponent)
    {
        this.mainActivityComponent = mainActivityComponent;
    }

    public void askForWritePermission()
    {
        boolean hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainActivityComponent, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        if (!hasPermission)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mainActivityComponent, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    public void verifyIfFolderExist()
    {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/TEST");

        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

Also in the manifest I am calling for:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!--  File save functions handles this  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Comment: Unclear what your problem is. Anyhow your app does not need any permission to create files in public Documents directory. So dont ask any.